# can't bind a viewmodel to a ResourceDictionary

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to bind my ViewModelBase in a ResourceDictionary so that I can call some of the properties to set the properties on my controls, for example I have a label and I want to set its color by one of the properties in my ViewModelBase...

Update: The ResourceDictionary resides in my styles folder and gets called on bootup, it does not reside in a page like so...

```
void LoadStyles()
{
    if (IsASmallDevice())
    {

       MyResources.MergedDictionaries.Add(SmallDevicesStyle.SharedInstance);
    }
    else
    {

       MyResources.MergedDictionaries.Add(GeneralDevicesStyle.SharedInstance);
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ResourceDictionary  xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:MyApp.ViewModels"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="MyApp.Styles.GeneralDevicesStyle">

    <viewModels:ViewModelBase x:Key="BaseView"/>

    <OnIdiom  x:TypeArguments="x:Double" Tablet="30" Phone="10" x:Key="PageSpacing" />
    <OnIdiom  x:TypeArguments="Thickness" Tablet="10" Phone="10" x:Key="PagePadding" />
    <Style TargetType="Label" x:Key="LabelStyle1">
        <Setter Property="FontSize">
            <Setter.Value>
                <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double" Phone="15" Tablet="15"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="FillAndExpand" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="FillAndExpand" />
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{Binding DefaultLabelColor}" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

```
   public class ViewModelBase : BaseViewModel
   {
     sting BackGroundColor = "aqua";
     public string DefaultBackGroundColor { get return BackGroundColor; }
   }
```

So my question is, How can I bind my ViewModelBase in my ResourceDictionary so that I can access the properties/Methods that reside in the ViewModelBase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the BindingContext for Label.

ViewModelBase:

```
 public class ViewModelBase
 {
    //public string DefaultBackGroundColor { get; set; } = "Aqua";
    private string BackGroundColor = "Aqua";
    public string DefaultBackGroundColor
    {        
        get { return BackGroundColor; }
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
 <ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <viewModels:ViewModelBase x:Key="BaseView" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
    <Style TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{Binding DefaultBackGroundColor}" />
        <Setter Property="BindingContext" Value="{StaticResource BaseView}"></Setter>
    </Style>
 </ContentPage.Resources>
 <ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Wendy, the style is in a separate file that resides in my styles folder and gets called on bootup, so I am not sure if this will work as you say, meaning it is not part of the page. Sorry for any misunderstanding, I will update my post.

Comment: Zang, ok I reacted to quickly again, your method works as well in my situation :-) I will put this post as answered

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that I did not clarify my answer correctly, I just had to add the following line into my StyleTarget properties `<Setter Property="BindingContext" Value="{StaticResource BaseView}"></Setter>` and then I could access all of the properties in my ViewModel.